# How do I get the current user’s info over Ajax?

Tags: users, ajax, current-user, plugin-elementapi

I created an Ajax-based login form based on this gist: https://gist.github.com/keithmancuso/29e8446ec5fa66fb2b01.

After the user has logged in, how can I get some info about them over Ajax?

Comment: I do not want to refresh the page for such a trifle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using the [Element API](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) plugin, with the following endpoints config:

```php
<?php
namespace Craft;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'user/info.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'User',
            'criteria' => [
                'id' => craft()->userSession->getId()
            ],
            'first' => true,
            'transformer' => function (UserModel $user) {
                return [
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'image' => $user->getPhotoUrl('28')
                ];
            },
        ]
    ]
];
```

Now after saving a user I can just create an Ajax request to `/user/info.json` and get their info in response.

Comment: Hey Vitaliy, I just updated your question and answer to make them more clear for other people in the future. I also added `'first' => true` to your endpoint config, which is going to slightly alter the response format, making it more optimized for a single user response. You can see how a single-user response differs from multi-user by looking at the [Examples section](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI#examples) in the Element API docs.

Answer (score 3):

For the redirect I agree, I could not get it too from ajax response, so I just saved it before the ajax call.
`var returnUrl = $("input[name='redirect']").val();`

Then I can make the redirection :

```
.success(function(data) {
    if (data.success) {
        window.location.href = returnUrl;
    }
```

For the user's data could you precise what you want to do?

Comment: I on the contrary do not want to redirect the user. I update question.